# Get primary key column of a table in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am totally new to using Oracle so I might not be using the right terminologies. Please excuse me for that.

I have the following query which helps me get the Primary key of a table in SQL Server

```
SELECT Col.Column_Name, Tab.Table_Name from 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS Tab, 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE Col 
WHERE Col.Constraint_Name = Tab.Constraint_Name 
AND Col.Table_Name = Tab.Table_Name 
AND Constraint_Type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
AND Col.Table_Name = 'EmployeeMaster'
```

So I want something similar which can help me get the column name of the table which has the primary key. Thanks in advance

Comment: How is c# relevant to this question?

Comment: @ZoharPeled sorry that was a mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT cols.table_name, cols.column_name, cols.position, cons.status, cons.owner
FROM all_constraints cons, all_cons_columns cols
WHERE cols.table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
AND cons.constraint_type = 'P'
AND cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
AND cons.owner = cols.owner
ORDER BY cols.table_name, cols.position;
```

**NOTE** replace  TABLE_NAME in upper case **your table**

Comment: Can you also help me with identity columns. How can I get the Identity columns of a table

Comment: I think There is no such thing as "auto_increment" or "identity" columns in Oracle. However, you can model it easily with a sequence and a trigger:

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot

Comment: Oracle introduced identity columns in 12c. Although as the question is tagged `[oracle11g]` this is not helpful here.