# Transform SQL Query to Oracle Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got this SQL Query that I need to write for Oracle, please could you help ?

```
SELECT key_column_usage.column_name
                FROM   information_schema.key_column_usage
                WHERE  table_schema = SCHEMA()     
                AND    constraint_name = 'PRIMARY' 
                AND    table_name = 'posts'
```

Comment: I don't understand your question - Oracle is rather good at SQL queries. Your query lacks the "select" clause, but appears to be querying MySQL's information schema  to look for primary keys on the table 'posts'. If that's what you want, this might answer your query. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42992649/get-primary-key-column-of-a-table-in-oracle

Comment: yes sorry, I forgot the select part. It's added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what parts of your query represent, but - let me try. It looks like you'd like to query *constraints* table. If so, then one option is to query `user_cons_columns`:

```
from user_cons_columns c
where c.owner = user
  and c.constraint_name = 'PRIMARY'
  and c.table_name = 'POSTS'
```

where

- `user` represents currently logged user
- `'PRIMARY'` is name of that constraint
- `'POSTS'` is table name; in Oracle, by default, table names are stored in UPPERCASE

---

Alternatively, join `user_constraints` and `user_cons_columns`:

```
from user_constraints r join user_cons_columns c on c.constraint_name = r.constraint_name
where r.owner = 'SCOTT'
  and r.constraint_type = 'P'
  and r.table_name = 'POSTS'
```

because `constraint_type = 'P'` represents *primary keys* (if that's what you actually want), and it is stored in `user_constraints`.

Just for example, this time I used `'SCOTT'` as an owner name.

---

If you want and/or have sufficient privileges, instead of `user_`, you can query `all_` or `dba_` views to fetch information you need. So, that would be e.g. `all_cons_columns` etc.

Comment: Good, I'm glad it is :)